# How to configure TeamCity to run the tests concurrently rather than one by one?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium, nunit, teamcity

I have some UI/system tests written with NUnit, C# and Seleium and I'm using TeamCity to run those tests automatically e.g. Once a day.

The problem is that each test takes between 1-10 minutes to complete and TeamCity runs them sequentially so it takes ages to get them all completed.

(please don't worry or comment about why the tests take so long because they are system tests and run for multiple users across multiple sites)

The tests are independent and don't rely on each other obviously therefore they can run concurrently.

How would that be possible to configure TeamCity to run the tests concurrently rather than one by one?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you might have to wait for 7.1:
http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-4300

Comment: The issue was rescheduled for version 8.0 on 10th July 2012. As it's now more than four years old I'm not optimistic that it will be implemented anytime soon.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to add more build servers. You cant run multiple instances in interactive mode as they will crosstalk

Answer (score 0):

More [Build Agents](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Build+Agent) can execute build configurations concurrently.

The build configurations are executed by Build Agents. It is very likely that you have one on the build server, where TeamCity is running. You can add another one on another machine. As far as I know it is not possible to have more than one Build Agent on one machine.

Comment: Yes you can have more than one build agent per machine. I have 4 each.

Answer (score 0):

TeamCity itself can not split NUnit task to several agents automatically.

You should split long-running tests into several build configurations. After that, these configurations can run on different build agents in parallel.